# Does Java have any equivalent to C++ string_view?

Tags: java, string, performance, immutability

Java has StringBuilder for generating strings that grow, but unfortunately most of the API uses String so everything requires conversion with attendant copy overhead.

On a compiler, suppose there is an array of char. Is there any class that can offer a read-only StringView (like C++17 string_view)? If not, I could easily write such as class, but the problem is since everything else deals in strings, some of the benefit would be lost.  The idea is to provide something that looks like a String where the constructor is just:

```
StringView(char[] bigBuffer, int start, int len) {}
```

and to use the class everywhere a string would be used.

Comment: You can just use a List of char. What's the actual use case?

Comment: A read-only array of characters is simply a string in Java since it is immutable to begin with. There's simply no need for a separate construct.

Comment: Since [JDK7u6](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6924259), Strings can no longer share underlying arrays. In order to benefit from "String views", you'll need to change API to use [CharSequence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html) instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an interface for read-only access of [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html)-like data. It's called [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html), and the `String` class implements this interface.

The Java equivalent to the C++ `StringView`, is a [`CharBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/CharBuffer.html), which also implements `CharSequence`, so any method that accepts a `CharSequence` can be called with a `String` or a `CharBuffer` (or a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)).

Many of the Java APIs already accept `CharSequence` instead of `String`, e.g. all of the `parse()` methods in the `java.time` package, as well as Java's regex API.

To create a `CharBuffer` in a similar way to how the `StringView` constructor works, you call [`wrap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#wrap(char%5B%5D,int,int)):

```java
CharBuffer.wrap​(char[] array, int offset, int length)
```

> The new buffer will be backed by the given char array; that is, modifications to the buffer will cause the array to be modified and vice versa.

That javadoc shows that no copying is going on.